Serilog configuration in .net core
I am trying to configure Serilog and was just testing if it works, but I am getting an error.
internal class SerilogLoggingTests
{
    private class MockSerilogSink : ILogEventSink
    {
        public List<LogEvent> LogEvents { get; } = new List<LogEvent>();

        public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
        {
            LogEvents.Add(logEvent);
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestSerilogLogger_UsingServiceProvider()
    {
        var _mockSink = new MockSerilogSink();

        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddSerilog(lc => lc.WriteTo.Sink(_mockSink));
        //serviceCollection.AddLogging(b => b.AddSerilog());
        using var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<SerilogLoggingTests>>();
        logger.LogInformation("This is a test log message.");    
        _mockSink.LogEvents.Count.Should().Be(1);
    }
}

The error I am getting is:

System.InvalidOperationException : No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[SerilogLoggingTests]' has been registered.

where as it works, if I uncomment the commented out line
//serviceCollection.AddLogging(b => b.AddSerilog());

As per documentation I don't need that commented out line, then why is it needed in this test?

Do you mean that it works after you delete serviceCollection.AddLogging(b => b.AddSerilog());? Or do you mean that it works after you uncomment it?

it works after I uncomment it

The AddLogging service collection extension registers the MS support functionaly for ILogger and ILogger<>.
